# CakePHP - calling a component 's function from a view and execute it on a button click

Tags: javascript, cakephp

How do I call a function from a component from a view? (ctp file)

I am using something like this:

```
App::import('Component', 'YourComponent');
$theComponent = new YourComponent();
$theComponent->yourMethod();
```

I want the line `$theComponent->yourMethod();` to be executed on a button click but instead it is executed upon page load...

here is a part of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function assign()
{
    var links_list = [];
                var links =document.getElementById('unassignedUsers').getElementsByTagName('a');
                for(var a in links) {
                    if(typeof links[a] == undefined) continue;
                    links_list.push(links[a].innerHTML);} var str =links_list.toString();
                    var array = str.split(',');
                    alert(array);
                 }
   <?php App::import('Model', 'Account');
    $account = new Account();  
   $account->insertPos();?> 
} 

<button id="button" name="button" onClick="assign();"> Save Changes </button>  
//this is the button i need the function to be executed when i click....
```

Please tell me what to do make the php code inside the javascript to be executed only when the button is clicked?

Comment: Executing PHP code from Javascript is not possible. PHP runs on the server, Javascript in the browser. What you can do though is sending a HTTP request to the server with Javascript to an URL that executes the PHP code you want. See Ajax for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $form->create('Account', array('action' => 'insertPos'));
echo $form->button('Save Changes', array('type' => 'submit'));
echo $form->end();
```

Comment: What does your whole ctp file look like?

Comment: it contains 4 lists each contains some draggable <a> tags and a button save changes...
when i use echo all of this disappears...

Answer (score 0):

Both cakephp and the internet work on specific architectures. Granted with Cakephp, it is easier to "break" the architecture and create work arounds, it is very difficult on the internet. The internet uses a client-server architecture where HTML, Javascript, and CSS work on the client-side, also known as the browser and php (along with other languages) operate on the server side. The server only interacts with the client-side after loading with an HTTPRequests (the easiest being AJAX). Only an HTTPRequest will trigger the server side run and that will always be done through an URL. Hence, the following is a rough model in which you should be following.

Client-side <---- HTTPRequest ----> Server-side

Given this and working with Cakephp, in order to follow best practices and gain the most from Cakephp, your request to save should be sent to a controller with the following URL: 
`www.yoursite.com/controller-name/save`

From here, assuming all values are in a form elements, your controller will only be sent the values in the form elements. Then within the controller the following should happen 
`$this->Account->insertPos();`

Best advice, if you want to make your website dynamic. Familiarize yourself with AJAX.